# Append HTML to HTML string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML string and I want to append another html string to this in some arbitrary location.

Example:

```
var htmlString = '<div id="insert"> <p> Hello </p> </div>'

var appendString = '<p> Goodbye </p>'

$(appendString).appendTo( $(htmlString).find('#insert') )
```

Obviously that doesn't work because it cannot insert directly into the string however, I do not want to convert htmlString into a jQuery object because it messes up the structure of the HTML document and I need the script tags to remain in the locations they have been inserted.

Hope that's clear enough.

EDIT:

My apologies, I think I explained my problem poorly.

I have a HTML string that includes a table and I want to append a new row to the table.  My problem is that I have a number of `<script>` tags that I need to remain in their locations.  When I convert the string into a $(string), I am then unable to return it to its original form:

```
var htmlString = $('body').html();
var $htmlString = $(x);
console.log($htmlString.html());
```

This is a Confluence page that I attempting to do this on and I have limited access to the source; most I can do is to modify what is already there.

The HTML string comes from a AJAX request of another page on Confluence and I need the scripts to remain in the same place so that my other macros will run correctly.

I have included a JS Bin example of my problem to hopefully illustrate my problem clearly.

https://jsbin.com/ruwawuzica/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```js
var htmlString = '<div id="insert"> <p> Hello </p> </div>';

var appendString = '<p> Goodbye </p>';
var added = ($(htmlString).append($(appendString)));
$(added).appendTo('div');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Since `$(htmlString)` is the `element` `<div id="insert"></div>` wrapped in `jquery`

Comment: What exactly asked in question was how we can insert good by a string in id="insert" part of HTML but what you have suggested is how we can append the html.

Answer (score 2):

Hi @MyLittleDax i guess you can do this:

```
var htmlString = "<div id='insert'> <p> Hello </p> </div>";
var appendString = "<p> Goodbye </p>";
//your container where you put the html
var container = $('#container'); 
container.empty();
container.append(htmlString);
var insert = $('#insert');
insert.append(appendString);
```

good luck!!!